# IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0 with bitmap.createBitmap method

Tags: android, bitmap

I have been struggling trying to get rid of this exception, my issue is everytime I try to re-build my image and position it at the center of my `framelayout` i get this error, before anything I am checking if the image is `null` or not, if not then am going ahead, and just before I call the `.createBitmap` method am measuring its dimensions which always seem to be `>0` but the `.createBitmap`method still throws the exception, here is my code:

```
 framelayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            original = getBitmap();
            if (original != null) {
                //where exception occurs
                setBitmap(original);
            }
        }
    });

    private void setBitmap(Bitmap original) {

    Bitmap scaledBitmap = scaledBitmap(original, sourceFrame.getWidth(), frameLayout.getHeight());
    sourceImageView.setImageBitmap(scaledBitmap);
    Bitmap tempBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) frameLayout.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    Map<Integer, PointF> pointFs = getEdgePoints(tempBitmap);
    polygonView.setPoints(pointFs);
    polygonView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    int padding = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.scanPadding);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(tempBitmap.getWidth() + 2 * padding, tempBitmap.getHeight() + 2 * padding);
    layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    polygonView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
}

   private Bitmap scaledBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int width, int height) {
    Matrix m = new Matrix();
    //dimensions are always greater than 0 when an image is picked
    //but still throws exception
    System.out.println("bitmap height: "+bitmap.getHeight());
    System.out.println("bitmap Width: "+bitmap.getWidth());
    m.setRectToRect(new RectF(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight()), new RectF(0, 0, width, height), Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);

         //exception occurs here
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), m, true);

}
```

at this point I am confused, I do not know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Error was being cause by my method that was picking the image from the gallery, it seems it was not picking and if it was something funny was happening.